# why is iText reader dependent on bouncy castle?

Tags: groovy, itext

The groovy environment in which I work has just been updated, and now even the simplest code I call to a reader is returning errors related to bouncy castle.

Where does this dependency exists and what is it doing?

I understand the use of BC to provide crypto classes when signing, but I can find no documentation that says I need it for the simple act of reading a file.

Is this related to a more recent version of iText?

My code really is this simple, and yet it returns the error..

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/RecipientId

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase

reader = new PdfReader(new File (fm_PDF)))
return true
```

Comment: `PdfReader` needs to be able to read encrypted files. It uses BouncyCastle to do so.

Comment: but there are a choice of methods, presumably for where I know if the file is encrypted or not.

Comment: PdfReader(InputStream is, byte[] ownerPassword) or PdfReader(InputStream is)     I can see why with the first, but does the second method require BC too??

Comment: If that is compiled in, than it does not matter.  you have to have the deps in classpath.

Comment: Helpful hint: mvnrepository.com is useful for finding transient  dependencies. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.5 shows a dependency on two bouncycastle libs and apache xmlsec for the latest iText.